# Should we use [r] and [markdown] or [r-markdown]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be some overlap between the tags [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) and [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) and users seem to use these tags inconsistently. At the time of posting there are...

- 139 questions tagged with [[r-markdown] and [markdown] and [r]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown+markdown+r)
- 356 questions tagged with [[markdown] and [r] but not [r-markdown]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown+r+-r-markdown)
- 30 questions tagged with [[markdown] and [r-markdown] but not [r]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown+r-markdown+-r)
- 2014 questions tagged [[r-markdown] and [r] but not [markdown]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown+r+-markdown)
- 357 questions tagged [[r-markdown] but not [r] or [markdown]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown+-r+-markdown)

I can see the use-case for some of these combinations, but not others. For example, many of the questions are simply [r] questions which happen to be in a Markdown context. However they have no relevance to Markdown specifically. In fact, those are the ones that bother me. Why litter the [markdown] tag with these questions. Shouldn't they be retagged to [r] and [r-markdown]? In fact, the [r] and [r-markdown] combination is the most popular.

And in the case of questions tagged  with [markdown] and [r] but not [r-markdown] presumably the OP simply missed that the [r-markdown] tag exists. Would it be reasonable to retag these?

I know there is such a thing as a synonym for a tag (some tags may even be auto-edited for new questions), but I'm assuming that doesn't work on a combination of tags. Any objection to someone (like myself) editing every new question of any combination above to remove the [markdown] tag?

I should note that there could be a few edge cases were the question actually relates to a [markdown] specific issue and the answer is not relevant to [r] (the OP's use of [r-markdown] is simply coincidental -- [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43773338/866026)). In those cases it might make sense to only use the [markdown] tag, except that the example could contain some [r] code, in which case [markdown] and [r-markdown] but not [r] would be relevant tags. Interestingly, that is the least popular combination in use.

---

Another option may be to not have tags for Markdown variants. Currently, we have the following tags:

- [r-markdown] with 2540
- [github-flavored-markdown] with 234
- [multimarkdown] with 40
- [markdownsharp] with 26
- [commonmark] with 22
- [markdowndeep] with 17
- [wmd-markdown] with 12
- [markdown4j] with 3
- [django-markdown-deux] and [python-markdown] with 0

Some of those aren't really variants, but tools or libraries.

Comment: There is also the minor annoyance the the "r" blends in with the "m" in [rmarkdown]. Maybe it would be more readable as [r-markdown].

Comment: Yeah, "rmarkdown" is impossible to read, so definitely not that one.

Comment: The thing is called "R Markdown" and SE replaces spaces with dash, so it should be [tag:R-Markdown]

Comment: `rmarkdown` is a [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html) in R. Many R packages have their own tags. So if someone wants to ask a quesiton related to *that specific package* they will probably use [tag:rmarkdown]. While for general question related to markdown and R integration, they will use the [tag:markdown] and [tag:r]. I'm not sure these tags are interchangeable.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that is not what the tag wiki suggests. By my reading, the [rmarkdown] tag is for questions related to markdown and R integration. Perhaps the tag wiki should be edited and the various questions re-tagged accordingly?

Comment: Yes, the wiki is incorrect. But I don't have time to edit it.

Comment: FYI, the [rmarkdown] tag has been [renamed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356031/866026) to [r-markdown] and this post has been edited to reflect that. Of course, various comments now seem out-of-place.

Answer (score 5):

The tags [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) and [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) themselves seem OK, unlike their usage.

**Tags on a question should reflect the technologies the question is *about*.** Each combination of the tags makes sense for some questions about scenarios where R and Markdown are used, but not for others.

The tags represent different concepts:

- [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is for the R programming language.
- [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) is for Markdown in general. Or maybe a little ambiguously for the original implementation `Markdown.pl` and its Markdown dialect, if there are still any questions about it.
- [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) is for R Markdown, the Markdown implementation and dialect related to R.

Using just [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is appropriate when asking about a bug in an R program that happens to generate Markdown output. Just [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) is appropriate when asking about the language itself, either without reference to any specific implementation, or with reference to one's own, custom implementation. Just [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) is appropriate when asking about this specific implementation or the dialect it uses (which is an extension to Pandoc Markdown).

Using more than one of the tags implies that the question is about multiple technologies, e.g. [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) when asking about how to implement a function in R that extracts all the link target URLs from a string containing Markdown. Other examples are in the question I'm answering.

If a question is **incorrectly tagged**, it can and **should be improved by editing**. But as the above entails, removing [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) will not always be correct.

**Synonymization** effectively **creates different names for the same tag**. Certainly not wanted here, as the tags represent different things, not different names for the same thing. A correct usage is to synonymize [rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rmarkdown) to [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown), which [has already been done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356031/2157640).