# Rename [rmarkdown] to [r-markdown]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

This is a request to rename the [rmarkdown] tag to [r-markdown] for the following reasons:

## Formatting

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) suggests:

> Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (e.g., tag "unit testing" as `unit-testing`)

And the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rmarkdown/info) clearly includes a space in the description:

> R Flavored Markdown or "R Markdown" is a markdown variant used for content-creation and/or programming documentation interleaved with R code.

## Readability

As pointed out in the comments to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354718/866026), due to lack of sufficient kerning, the "r" blends in with the "m" and the tag is easily mistaken for [markdown].

Including the hyphen would resolve both issues.

Finally, should [rmarkdown] be made a synonym of [r-markdown], or will the system prevent that tag from being recreated as the only difference is the hyphen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeesh! You're right, that tag name was nigh-unreadable.

[image: BAD KERNING & Signage Awards]
<sub>(Image courtesy of ["The World's Greatest Book", by Dave Bricker.](http://theworldsgreatestbook.com/bad-kerning/))</sub>

So...

Tag has been renamed, so (caching notwithstanding) all questions previously tagged [rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rmarkdown) are now tagged [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown).

I also created a synonym mapping from [rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rmarkdown) to [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown), just in case. The hyphen would not have been automatically ignored by the system.

The [previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354718/should-we-use-r-and-markdown-or-rmarkdown) regarding whether [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) or [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)+[markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) should be preferred still remains unresolved, from my perspective (and I don't have a strong opinion either way), but renaming the extant tag to something more readable in the meantime does not complicate any future retagging efforts.